# Is there an emulator for the Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch

I was wondering if there were any simulators that I could download that would emulate the functionality of an Apple Watch?

I know the watch was just released, but is there something that simulates its functionality?

Comment: Afaik there isn't. You can simulate the Watch in XCode for Development http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756413/how-can-i-simulate-the-apple-watch-for-development-purposes# but it's not a full kind of simulation of the whole device

Answer (score 5):

You can simulate the Apple Watch using the latest version of Xcode on the Mac AppStore.

To run a watch app, you run the app on the iPhone Simulator with an Apple Watch target (the target is added in the Xcode project). The Watch Simulator then starts automatically.

You will need the source code for both the iPhone and watch apps.